# Suplemenatary material for Algebraic Curves by Fulton

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, self-learning

I am making plans to read Fulton's Algebraic Curves by myself in a span of 5-6 months. Is there any lecture note available online for this text? I will be trying to follow [this](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Ekhonigs/818/) course as much as possible.

Comment: I want to mention another reference you may appreciate having alongside with Fulton's text, namely [complete lecture notes](https://agag-gathmann.math.rptu.de/en/curves.php) by Andreas Gathmann on plane algebraic curves.

Comment: Notes by Timothy Ford: http://math.fau.edu/ford/syllabi/S16/MAS6396/AlgebraicCurves.pdf

Comment: thank you for the comments.